# How to access user names and profiles with django-allauth

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-authentication

I'm using Django with django-allauth for social authentication.

I have authentication up and running, but can anyone give simple examples of how to:

- show the name and avatar of a logged-in user
- add some information to a user's account?

For example, on the home page, I've got

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<li><a href="{% url account_logout %}?next=/">Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

That's showing the Logout link correctly, but how would I add the user's name and avatar?

Something like (pseudocode):

```
<p>You're logged in with {{ user.account_provider? }} as {{ user }}.</p>
<img src="{{ user.avatar_url }}" />
```

Then, if I want to add extra properties to the user's profile, what do I do? Should I be using some other Django user-related app?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did the answer provided help? I have the same question as you did, and would like to know the answer please?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer over at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222021/how-can-i-get-the-users-facebook-id-with-django-allauth/12226639#12226639 It shows the correct way to get your hands on the avatar URL et al.

Answer (score 14):

A `SocialAccount` model instance is available for users who signed up using their social account.

In your template, you can simply write:

**Avatar URL:** `{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}`
**UID:** `{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.uid }}`
**Date Joined:** `{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.date_joined}}`
**Last Login:** `{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.last_login}}`

And for **Full Name:** `{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.extra_data.name }}`

For more information: [Django allauth source](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L89)

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern Django (`1.11.x`) and allauth (`0.32.x`).

Answer (score 4):

If you look at django-allauth source https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L7

This is an abstract model that represents all the methods all other specific service models have. Thus you could write

```
<p>You're logged in with {{ user.get_provider }} as {{ user }}.</p>
<img src="{{ user.get_avatar_url }}" />
```

Comment: These get_provider() and get_avatar_url() methods do not seem to be propagating onto the user object with recent django and django-allauth. Seems like this requires manually populating the context.

Comment: SocialAccount class still has these methods. Are you sure you have SocialAccount instance in context?

Comment: I have the allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount context processor active which places a 'socialaccount' dict in the context; the entries in this dict are the active providers. I don't see how this (or the SocialAccount model) modifies the user object, though, permitting access like '{{user.get_provider}}'. Am I missing your point entirely, maybe? Sorry, I'm relatively new to allauth, django, and python so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

you can make for loop in set of socialaccount within foreignkey to user class, in the template it's something like below :

```
{% for account in user.socialaccount_set.all %}

 {% comment %} show avatar from url {% endcomment %}
 <h2 style="text-transform:capitalize;">{{ account.provider }} account data</h2>

 <p><img width="50" height="50" src="{{ account.get_avatar_url }}"/></p>

 <p>UID: <a href="{{ account.extra_data.link }}">{{ account.uid }}</a></p>

 <p>Username: {{ account.extra_data.username }}</p>

  <p>First Name: {{ account.extra_data.first_name }}</p>

  <p>Last Name: {{ account.extra_data.last_name }}</p>

  <p>Dashboard Link: 
  <a href="{{ account.extra_data.link }}">{{ account.extra_data.link }}</a></p>
  {% empty %}
  <p>you haven't any social account please</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i got stock here too yesterday, i have gone round the internet for solution but none was looking as understandable as what i came up with...
After installation and configuration of the allauth package, i did the following:

1. create a signal.py file in app directory
2. Inside your venv locate the allauth package
3. Then navigate to allauth/socialaccount/models.py
4. This way you can have a better understanding on how to grab models from the allauth package or call other functions and classes
5. In app/signal.py do this:

   ```
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save;p0-
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from .models import Profile
    from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount# step 3 made this possible
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    @receiver(post_save, sender = SocialAccount)
    def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       if created:
          # Grabbing data from social account to create profile for that user
          profile=Profile(
                 user=instance.user,
                 photo=instance.extra_data['picture']
                         )
          profile.save()
        else:
       # Do something else
   ```

You see that the sender of the signal is the model "SocialAccount", because this model is always created during authentication, then grab the field "extra_data" which is a dictionary and then the key "['picture']" from the JSON object in the field "extra_data"... I hope this works for you. Thank you

This way you are able to grab the values of the picture and also assign the user with a profile