# Does allauth support UserProfile models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-allauth

I read one can create a Signup form using allauth, but does it also support UserProfile models as described in the Django documentation?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: Not familiar with allauth, but if you find it too limiting, you may also be interested in https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts.  It's been working great for me, and it's definitely compatible with UserProfile models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to put up a custom signup form, ask the user for his favorite color, and store that in a project specific UserProfile as you please. `allauth` does not get in the way with 
standard Django behavior on this point.

Have a look here on how to set up a custom signup form:

[How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth)