# django-allauth: custom user generates IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/ (custom fields are nulled or lost)

Tags: django-allauth, django-1.6, django-custom-user

I'm trying to integrate django-allauth with a custom user model (subclassed AbstractUser, but when I test the signup form I get an integrity error due to field (date_of_birth) being null, but the value submitted was u'1976-4-6'

I'm learning the new custom user stuff, as well as class-based views as I'm learning django-allauth, so I'm confident that I'm doing something wrong, but after a couple days of reading the github issues, the few tutorials, readthedocs, and stackoverflow questions I still have no clear idea of what I'm doing wrong (well I know one thing I'm doing wrong:  trying different solutions here and there, so I definitely have a miss-mosh of implementations)

But, I can't find a good answer on how to integrate allauth with a subclassed AbstractUser, so if anyone could enlighten me, I would really appreciate it.

(Note - the site is more or less working when I log in as a user that I've loaded via fixtures, so please assume that non-django-allauth omissions are omissions - if you need clarification on something not below, I will happily edit)

#### settings.py

```python
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userdata.CtrackUser'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'userdata.forms.SignupForm'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

#### userdata/models.py

```python
class CtrackUser(AbstractUser):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(help_text='YYYY-MM-DD format')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, 
    choices=settings.GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    race = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=settings.RACE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    condition = models.ForeignKey(Condition, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    my_symptoms = models.ManyToManyField(Symptom)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

#### userdata/forms.py

```python
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from allauth.account.forms import SetPasswordField, PasswordField
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
from medical.models import Condition


class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=80,required=True,)
    password1 = SetPasswordField()
    password2 = PasswordField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False,)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False,)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField()   
    gender = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=settings.GENDER_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-lg'}),
        required=False,)
    race = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=settings.RACE_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-lg'}),
        required=False,)
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=255,required=False,)
    condition = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Condition.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-lg'}),
        empty_label='Select condition (optional)'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model() # use this function for swapping user model
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1',  'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'race', 'location', 'condition', 'confirmation_key',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'signup_form'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-xs-6'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-xs-12'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'accounts_signup'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Sign up'))

    def signup(self, request, user, model):
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        model.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        model.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
        model.race = self.cleaned_data['race']
        model.location = self.cleaned_data['location']
        model.condition = self.cleaned_data['condition']
        model.save()
        user.save()
```

#### templates/allauth/account/signup.html

```
<form id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="form-inline">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% crispy form %}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
{#  <div class="form-actions">#}
{#  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>#}
{#  </div>#}
</form>
```

#### POST data

```
u'condition'  [u'1']
u'confirmation_key' [u'']
u'date_of_birth' [u'1976-4-6']
u'email' [u'1@bt.co']
u'first_name' [u'One']
u'gender' [u'']
u'last_name' [u'Person']
u'location' [u''] u'password1' [u'123456'] 
u'password2' [u'123456']
u'race' [u'']
u'submit' [u'Sign up']
u'username' [u'gn']
```

#### Error generated (note difference from post data)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/

Exception Value: null value in column "date_of_birth" violates not-null constraint

DETAIL:  Failing row contains (19, pbkdf2_sha256$12000$exNVzh4QI0Rb$mCTz9Tc+TIBbD8+lIZs2B3hqjxd+qmI..., 2014-07-02 16:27:43.751428+00, f, gn, One, Person, 1@bt.co, f, t, 2014-07-02 16:27:43.751473+00, null, , null, null, null, f, 2014-07-02 16:27:43.833267+00, 2014-07-02 16:27:43.83329+00).

Full traceback here:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hanleybrand/ee260b53dfb404f5055a/raw/3325dc746120c4f7521b9b976abce45dd7d71a77/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer -- which I'm still figuring out -- seems to be that if you are saving a model that contains field types that `allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter` doesn't handle correctly (e.g. any field that lacks a `__getitem__` attribute, like `models.DateField`) it is necessary to implement a custom adapter somewhat like below.

**note**: *your subclassed abstract user model is the user that's passed in, so the best practice is to use the form data directly like* `user.email = data.get('email')` *rather than using the allauth internal methods used in the DefaultAccountAdapter class*

#### userdata/adapter.py

```py
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.email = data.get('email')
        user.username = data.get('username')
        # all your custom fields
        user.date_of_birth = data.get('date_of_birth')
        user.gender = data.get('gender')
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data["password1"])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()
        self.populate_username(request, user)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```