# django-allauth - Overriding default signup form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm using this code (in forms.py) for my custom signup form for allauth:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_DATE_YEARS))

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth_date', 'city', 'country')
```

I have of course specified `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` in settings.py to point to this form and it displays the fields which I've put in it. However, it does not work on submission, even if I put `signup` method it never gets invoked. I've tried with the `save` but still it's the same - it raises an error that one of my custom added fields is blank while creating user and saving it to the database.
So, what's the correct code for achieving this?

Comment: maybe you have missing allauth option in your project setting! please look my answer and try to adapt

Comment: I don't, as I stated above I've set `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` and the form is displayed with all fields correctly. The problem is submission of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've made it thanks to [@rakwen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4864859/rakwen) who has found the correct solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536774/django-allauth-custom-user-generates-integrityerror-at-accounts-signup-custo#answer-24622274). I wrote my custom adapter and put it in adapters.py in my app:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.username = data['username']
        user.email = data['email']
        user.first_name = data['first_name']
        user.last_name = data['last_name']
        user.gender = data['gender']
        user.birth_date = data['birth_date']
        user.city = data['city']
        user.country = data['country']
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data['password1'])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()
        self.populate_username(request, user)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Then I've specified `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` in settings.py to point to that adapter, and it finally started to work!

Answer (score 4):

In your project setting.py try to add this line:

verify if you have added this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = "yourapp.forms.customSignupForm"
```

In app.models

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):
    """CustomModel docstring."""

    city = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    other....
```

In app.forms:

```
class SignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """SignForm docstring."""

    username = forms.CharField(
        max_length=30,
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=30,
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=30,
    )
    field...

    def myclean():

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """You signup function."""


    # dont forget to save your model

    class Meta:
        model = mymodel.CustomModel
        fields = [
            'city',
            'country',
            'field...',
        ]
```

Try this method work !

Comment: question: You have a custom models called User ?

Comment: Yes, I have custom User model with my custom extra fields.

Comment: if not create a profile or other like it, this model must have a oneToOne relation with django user and add your current other fields. create a modelForm not a simple form. Look i adapt my answer with your context.

Comment: Tried everything, and still `signup` method never gets invoked. It seems more like an issue with allauth itself rather than my code.

Comment: look my answer and do like it !

Comment: refresh this page and look my answer again !

Comment: I've looked at it and I've already done and configured the same - the same code for forms.py is in my main question. Only `myclean()` isn't present there, so what's that method meant for, I don't understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108577/discussion-between-rakwen-and-mikisoft).

Comment: ok.so u guys moved to chat but left us all unanswered with i que..what dows myclean() do.  @rakwen  could u help here

Comment: ronit How are you ? I can help you !