# django-allauth signup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

As you can imagine i'm new to django. İ tried to use allauth package for signup-in issues. After studying bunch of basic tutorials etc. the basic configuration started to function just fine but i needed custom signup process for my project.

So i started to dig more and implemented this topic to my code --
[1]: [django-allauth: custom user generates IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/ (custom fields are nulled or lost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536774/django-allauth-custom-user-generates-integrityerror-at-accounts-signup-custo)

After the implementation i started to debug various issues caused by django-version difference but eventually i ve got the following error:

```
TypeError at /accounts/signup/

signup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version:     3.2.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

signup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
```

the topics and pastebin links that i've found are not working anymore. thats why i'm stucked with this error. i think im missing something basic but cant figure it out. Here are my model-form-settings and adapters below:

models.py

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings

class CtrackUser(AbstractUser):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(help_text='YYYY-MM-DD format')
    country = CountryField()
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from APP.models import CtrackUser
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from allauth.account.forms import SetPasswordField,PasswordField
from django.db import models
from APP.models import CtrackUser
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=80,required=True,)
    password1 = SetPasswordField()
    password2 = PasswordField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False,)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False,)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField()
    country = CountryField().formfield()
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField().formfield()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1',  'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'country','phone_number')



    def signup(self, request, user, model):
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        model.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        model.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        model.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        model.save()
        user.save()
```

adapter.py

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.email = data.get('email')
        user.username = data.get('username')
        # all your custom fields
        user.date_of_birth = data.get('date_of_birth')
        user.first_name = data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = data.get('last_name')
        user.country = data.get('country')
        user.phonenumber = data.get('phonenumber')
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data["password1"])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()
        self.populate_username(request, user)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS=7
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'   
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'


ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'APP.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "APP.CtrackUser"
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'APP.forms.SignupForm'
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'APP.adapter.AccountAdapter'

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

Comment: remove the `model` from the `def signup(self, request, user, model):` (and also the lines that work with that model).

Comment: oh you'are right. trying to figure it out from different resources made it complicated. thank you.