# How to add extra fields after fb auth in Django allauth

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

How to add an extra field to django allauth registration flow.

1. First step- Django allauth registration using email or fblogin 
 (this is working for me, the user is able to register through facebook or email)
2. I want to add the following fields/attributes to the user registration but as a second step.

[image]

The new attributes are 1. DOB, Address, Phone no, Linkedin login and a user profile score

Answer (score 0):

Answer to block one can be found here
[How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth)

for Block 2, 
Add this to your settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = ('allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
)