# Django-allauth: custom signup form for socialaccount

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth) (and the doc) that one can use ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS to define some custom form field presented during account registration. However, this form does not seem to appear in the flow of using a social account (at least not by default).

Is there a way to have it, or to easily customize some handlers so that I could introduce such step ? Otherwise, this would give a quite non-unified signup process (people using social accounts would have to go and fill the information afterwards in some settings screen, rather than just being asked it once).

Comment: You could set `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False`. Upon successful authentication the user will be redirected to your signup form. This also kicks in if the email is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you can defined [SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) in your settings to set your own custom social signup form:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'myproject.myapp.forms.CustomSocialSignupForm'
}
```