# Customising django-allauth's socialaccount signup form

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am successfully using my custom form class with the standard account signup, however I can't seem to be able to use a custom form class for the social account signup (the default signup form is always loaded).

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155884/django-allauth-custom-signup-form-for-socialaccount) question, I've set `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False`. And as suggested in the [django-allauth docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html), I am using the following setting:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'someapp.forms.SocialSignupForm'
}
```

The code for the custom form class looks something like this (so pretty much whats been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth)):

```
class SocialSignupForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label='Foo', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Bar'}))

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.foo = self.cleaned_data['foo']
        user.save()
```

Comment: this is not longer working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem was that the setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS` (and therefore the customisation of the Signup form) is only available from django-allauth 0.17.1 onwards.

My installed version is 0.17.0 (installed via pip), currently, 0.17.1 needs to be installed from source.