# How to add max_length to allauth username

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using Django allauth as my user account framework for my django site. The docs show there is an [ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) however there is no `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH` for some reason.

Is there any way to create a max length for username?

Here's my custom allauth signup form - maybe I can do something here?:

```
class AllauthSignupForm(forms.Form):

    captcha = ReCaptchaField(
        public_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY"),
        private_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY"),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """ Required, or else it throws deprecation warnings """
        pass
```

**Edit:** Trying to subclass SignupView

**draft1/forms.py**

```
class AllauthSignupForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AllauthSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username']['validators'] += MaxLengthValidator(150,
                                                                    "Username should be less than 150 character long")

    captcha = ReCaptchaField(
        public_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY"),
        private_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY"),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """ Required, or else it throws deprecation warnings """
        pass
```

**draft1/views.py**

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView

class MySignupView(SignupView):
    form_class = AllauthSignupForm
```

**allauth/account/urls.py**

```
url(r"^signup/$", MySignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),
```

**draft1/settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'draft1.forms.AllauthSignupForm'
```

The above code returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/vorsso/venvor/draft1/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/vorsso/venvor/draft1/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .forms import UserSettingsForm
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/vorsso/venvor/draft1/forms.py", line 8, in <module>
    from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 228, in <module>
    class BaseSignupForm(_base_signup_form_class()):
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 216, in _base_signup_form_class
    fc_classname))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "draft1.forms" does not define a "AllauthSignupForm" class
```

Comment: I have created this [pull request](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/2038) regarding adding `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH` setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be quickly done by extending `DefaultAccountAdapter` class and overriding the `clean_username` method. You need to also reference the `clean_username` once again after our custom validation to complete other inbuilt validations.

It can be done as follows.

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django.forms import ValidationError

class UsernameMaxAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_username(self, username):
        if len(username) > 'Your Max Size':
            raise ValidationError('Please enter a username value less than the current one')
        return DefaultAccountAdapter.clean_username(self,username) # For other default validations.
```

Finally, point to the subclass in your settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'YourProject.adapter.UsernameMaxAdapter'
```

Reference: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/8fbbf8c1d32832d72de5ed1c7fd77600af57ea6f/allauth/account/adapter.py#L244

Comment: Thankyou so much! I've tried everything and this is the only thing that works and it is also very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a max length validator like below. More documentation about validators [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/#maxlengthvalidator).

```
from django.core.validators import MaxLengthValidator
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class AllauthSignupForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['username']['validators'] += MaxLengthValidator(150, "Username should be less than 150 character long")
```

Comment: Tried that but getting this error `'SignupForm' object has no attribute 'fields'` .. any idea?

Comment: Your form should extend allauth SignupForm like in my edited post.

Comment: Also I think you access username field with self.username

Comment: When I change `forms.Form` to `SignupForm` it gives this error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "draft1.forms" does not define a "AllauthSignupForm" class` - any idea?

Comment: I think that you need to call the super `__init__` first: `super(AllauthSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` before to use the `self.fields`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but it works.

After extending the `SignupForm`, Completely changed the `username` field with a new one that has the `max_length` parameter.

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class AllauthSignupForm(SignupForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"),
                               min_length=5,
                               max_length=20, # Change this 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(
                                   attrs={'placeholder':
                                              _('Username'),
                                          'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
```

Comment: When I change `forms.Form` to `SignupForm` I get this error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "draft1.forms" does not define a "AllauthSignupForm" class` - Any idea? I imported `SignupForm` aswell

Comment: @Zorgan check this: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1749#issuecomment-304628013

Answer (score 0):

I would like to explain why there is no `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH`. If you open source code you will see that `max_length` validator comes from `username` model field https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/330bf899dd77046fd0510221f3c12e69eb2bc64d/allauth/account/forms.py#L277

```
username_field.max_length = get_username_max_length()
```

Where `get_username_max_length` is function that actually pulls `max_length` value from `User` model https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/8fbbf8c1d32832d72de5ed1c7fd77600af57ea6f/allauth/utils.py#L64

```
def get_username_max_length():
    from .account.app_settings import USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD
    if USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD is not None:
        User = get_user_model()
        max_length = User._meta.get_field(USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD).max_length
    else:
        max_length = 0
    return max_length
```

**First approach:** So you could change `max_length` value directly on your `User`'s model `username` field if you have it swapped.

I don't think overriding form fields or `__init__` method will actually work the it suggested by other answers, because assign of `max_length` happens in subclass of `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/330bf899dd77046fd0510221f3c12e69eb2bc64d/allauth/account/forms.py#L259

```
class BaseSignupForm(_base_signup_form_class()):
```

where `_base_signup_form_class` is function that gets your `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS`

**Second approach:** is to subclass `SignupView` and override it's `SignupForm` read [Override signup view django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923776/override-signup-view-django-allauth) and [How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth)

In that `SignupForm` you could actually do what @MehdiB or @PeterSobhi suggested.

`ImproperlyConfigured` issue occurs because of https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1792

So you be sure that these forms are defined in different python modules as per https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1749#issuecomment-304628013

```
# base/forms.py 
# this is form that your ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS is points to
class BaseSignupForm(forms.Form):

    captcha = ReCaptchaField(
        public_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY"),
        private_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY"),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """ Required, or else it throws deprecation warnings """
        pass

# data1/forms.py
# this is your signup form
from django.core.validators import MaxLengthValidator
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class MySignupForm(SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username']['validators'] += MaxLengthValidator(150, "Username should be less than 150 character long")

# views.py

from allauth.account.views import SignupView
class MySignupView(SignupView):
    form_class = MySignupForm

# urls.py

url(r"^signup/$", MySignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the 2nd method but got a `ImproperlyConfigured: Module "draft1.forms" does not define a "AllauthSignupForm" class` error. Not sure why - I've added my code and the Traceback in the edit if you'd like to look.

Comment: Just tried that - there were no errors however it doesn't decrease `max_length`. My settings are `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'draft1.forms.BaseSignupForm'` and I ensured the 2 forms are in 2 different modules, but still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @Zorgan what database you are using?

Comment: I'm using postrgresql (psycopg2) as my database

Comment: @Zorgan Are you sure you are using overridden view instead of default one?

Comment: If by that you mean `MySignupView.as_view()` then yeah I was using that. But do you think there is any problem with reducing `max_length` via javascript? `$("#id_username").attr('maxlength','25');`?

Comment: @Zorgan I meant, are you sure that your django project actually uses it. Try putting breakpoint or something in MySignupView to see if it is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing with the full name like in your forms :
 from allauth.accouts import forms as AllauthForms 
class AllauthSignupForm(AllauthForms.SignupForm):
    ....

i didn't test this and sorry i posted this with my phone i will reformat  the answer soon