# Creating custom fields with Django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-allauth

I'm trying to include custom fields for the Django allauth SignUp form without much success. I've created the following forms and models:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', unique=True)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import forms
from .models import UserProfile

class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'website', 'picture') 

    def save(self, user): 
        profile.save()
        user.save()
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_app.UserProfile'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'user_app.forms.SignupForm'
```

I've receiving the following error:
**AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'**

1. Is this the correct way to extend the base class?
2. For the profile page, how do I load the extended class instead of the user class, so that I can display the username that is logged in?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

You can read this doc about custom user

Comment: Have a look at this question answered by Django allauth author: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12303478/247696

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a tuple called `REQUIRED_FIELDS` in your model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('user',)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', unique=True)
```