# Is there any solutions to add captcha to Django-allauth?

Tags: captcha, django-allauth

Is there any solutions to use captcha with django-allauth?
I want to use captcha on registration form for standard email+password registrations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I too needed to do this with django-allauth and found that implementing the [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha) package to be relatively simple.

### Configure django-recaptcha

Sign up for a [recaptcha account](https://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Plug your settings in

```
# settings.py

RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'xyz'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = 'xyz'

RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL = True     # Defaults to False
```

### Customize SignupForm

After installing django-recaptcha, I followed some[guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth) for customizing the SignupForm.

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class AllAuthSignupForm(forms.Form):

    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    def save(self, request, user):
        user = super(AllAuthSignupForm, self).save(request)
        return user
```

You also need to tell allauth to inherit from this form in settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.AllAuthSignupForm'
```

### Wire up signup form template

`{{ form.captcha }}` and `{{ form.captcha.errors }}` should be available on the signup template context at this point.

That was it!  Seems like all the validation logic is tucked into the `ReCaptchaField`.

Comment: I have tried with latest version of django-allauth and it doesn't required template changes. Just add new captcha field in model and that's it.

Comment: That's brilliant. Is there any way the captcha field can be added at the very end. I am using django-allauth app.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra did u manage to get the captcha field at the very end? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Zorgan No (Using django-allauth). So I had to use django-recaptcha package and then inside signupform in forms.py, I put `captcha = ReCaptchaField(attrs={'theme' : 'clean'})`. Before that I had to import `from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField` .

Comment: the django-recaptcha doesn't allow the captcha to be optional, so I rolled my own solution for server side captcha https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha/issues/217

Comment: I think the edits to this post might be incorrect...  see https://bhoey.com/blog/integrating-recaptcha-with-django-allauth/ which is identical to the original post, and does work as of October 2020

Answer (score 3):

To get the ReCaptcha field to the bottom of the form, simply add the other fields before the captcha field. 
So what was `user, email, captcha, password1, password2` becomes `user, email, password1, password2, captcha` with this form:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm, PasswordField
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class UpdatedSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    password1 = PasswordField(label=_("Password"))
    password2 = PasswordField(label=_("Password (again)"))
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(UpdatedSignUpForm, self).save(request)
        return user
```

You then just need to add this form into the `settings.py` file as described in the previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at [Form.field_order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order).

So a simple sign up form using django-allauth, with captcha and the fields ordered as you wish, would look like this:

```py
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField


class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    field_order = ['email', 'password1', 'captcha']
```

In this case, the captcha will be at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is mostly fine, but produced this error for me when submitting the sign up form:

```
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

To fix this, your custom form could look like this

```py
class AllAuthSignupForm(forms.Form):

    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    def signup(self, request, user):
        pass
```

NOTE: `django-allauth` also warns if the custom signup form does not have `signup` method.