# Display google recpatcha at the end of the form django-allauth app

Tags: python, django, django-recaptcha

I am creating a signup form using django(1.10) allauth app. I have installed django-recaptcha app from - https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha

The captcha is working but it is showing after the field 'Organisation' as I am calling the module after 'Organisation' field. Is there any way so that the field displays at the end after password field.

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Field
from ajax_select.fields import AutoCompleteSelectField, AutoCompleteField
from phonenumber_field.formfields  import PhoneNumberField
from . import models
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField


class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(label=_("Phone (Please state your country code eg. +44)"))
    organisation = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(attrs={'theme' : 'clean'})
```

signup.html

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}

  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

SO reference -- [Is there any solutions to add captcha to Django-allauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665211/is-there-any-solutions-to-add-captcha-to-django-allauth)

Screenshot --

[image]

The captcha needs to put after 'password again' field. Do I need to create sub class or something like that?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using the django-recpatch module? I simply bring a JS file of google recaptcha to my forms and validate them in django by sending a request to the API. Works pretty clean. There you only need to declare an html div below the form fields or wherever you need it to be.

Comment: using recaptcha field is just consistency with django forms that's all. Explicit field will make it hard for validation and everything else

Comment: Can you post your html you are using with this form?. This is certainly a problem with html not the form class

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Sure. I will update my post now.

Comment: Post updated. I tried using {{ form.captcha }} in signup.html but no luck.

Comment: individual field rendering should work. Did you try rendering every field individually like form.first_name, form.last_name ..... What error does it show if you do that

Comment: Yes I just tried. But there is no error. form.first_name display the field.

Comment: There is something called field_order but do not know how to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had to overwrite the default one in this way

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(label=_("Phone (Please state your country code eg. +44)"))
    organisation = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(attrs={'theme' : 'clean'})
```

May be this is not the nicest way but relief for time being. Please any suggestions are highly welcomed.