# How to solve a DeprecationWarning I get after customizing the user profile?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I customized the user profile like suggested in this question: [How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth/12308807#12308807)

So basically my code looks like this:

- In forms.py:

  ```
  class SignupForm(forms.Form):
      first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label=_("First Name"))
      last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label=_("Last Name"))

      def save(self, user):
          user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
          user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
          user.save()
  ```
- In settings.py:

  ```
  ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'core.forms.SignupForm'
  ```

The code works fine and I get the complete form with First Name and Last Name in the sign up form, but I get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: The custom signup form must offer a def signup(self, request, user) method DeprecationWarning)
```

**Question: What do I have to do with `def signup(self, request, user) method` in order to solve this warning?**

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, but what do I have to put inside it? What does it has to do? Could you post an example please? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#upgrading) the deprecation warning in favor of `def signup(self, request, user)`:

> Previously, the save(user) was called on the custom signup form.
>   However, this shadowed the existing save method in case a model form
>   was used. To avoid confusion, the save method has been deprecated in
>   favour of a def signup(request, user) method.

So just implement the method. And do what ever you were doing in `def save()` in `def signup()` There is no need of `def save()`.

```
def signup(self, request, user):
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.save()
```