# How to pass additional user info with django python-social-auth oauth2 authentication?

Tags: django, python-social-auth

How can I pass additional user information with python-social-auth such that they are saved to the database upon successful authentication?

I looked into pipelines but could not figure this out.

I have a form with sign up button which will start the social auth process and I would like these form values to be stored.

Comment: I think this can help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth

Comment: @Ashwath, you need a view to process your form and store the values in the session (or another place), then in a pipeline function you can retrieve those values and store them were you want. Check the pipeline doc at http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline