# django allauth custom signup form to assign different groups

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have two types of users in the system, I want to assign the appropriate group at the time of signing up. Referring to [How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth), I thought I can override the Signup form and do something like:

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    login_widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'email',
                                              'placeholder': _('email'),
                                              'autofocus': 'autofocus',
                                              'class': 'form-control'
                                      })

    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=login_widget)
    password = PasswordField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = PasswordField(label='Re-type Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def save(self, request, user):
        role = request.GET.get('type')
        print(role)
        group = role or "group1"
        g = Group.objects.get(name=group)
        user.groups.add(g)
        user.save()
```

But I keep getting the error below:

```
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

Also, I have configured allauth to use email to login.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

signup is the method to override not save.

```
class LocalSignupForm(forms.Form):
    pass

    def signup(self, request, user):
        role = request.session.get('user_type')
        group = role or "Default"
        g = Group.objects.get(name=group)
        user.groups.add(g)
        user.save()
```

Also the settings has to be

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'useraccount.forms.LocalSignupForm'
```