# How to assign a user automatically to a group on signup, using Django Allauth

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

So I want to assign a user on signup to a specific group. I am using Django Allauth. I found some posts on SO but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is my code:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'text',
               'placeholder': _('First name')}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'text',
               'placeholder': _('Last name')}))
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(
        attrs={'type': 'date',
               'placeholder': _('Date of birth')}))
    privacy = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.birth_date = self.cleaned_data['birth_date']
        user.privacy = self.cleaned_data['privacy']

        role = request.session.get('user_type')
        group = role or "Default"
        g = Group.objects.get(name='Premium')
        user.groups.add(g)
        user.save()
        return user
```

However this is not working, the user does not get assigned to the group "Premium" after signup.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where does your `SignupForm` originates from?

Comment: What do you mean @WillemVanOnsem?

Comment: did you set a `SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` setting?

Comment: Is the `user` object already in the database by the time it gets to this method?

Comment: Yes I set `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
'signup': 'myod.users.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}` it's the new approach

Comment: By the way the custom signup is working perfectly fine, with my own defined form fields. The only thing not working is the group assignment

Comment: I added the full `CustomSignupForm` block now in my question, maybe there are some errors in the  lines before

Comment: @RafRasenberg: what if you first `user.save()`, and *then* perform `user.groups.add(g)`? Usually an object first needs to be saved, before you can add relations to other objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem unfortunately that did not work. If I see this SO post, the above piece of code SHOULD work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180427/django-allauth-custom-signup-form-to-assign-different-groups

Answer (score 0):

**Raf Rasenberg**, try to check this thread: ["django allauth custom signup form to assign different groups"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180427/django-allauth-custom-signup-form-to-assign-different-groups/74553297). I was able to assign the user to a specific group based on the chosen field upon signup. I'm using custom user profile based on AbstractUser class and LocalSignupForm(forms.Form) with ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = "studios.forms.LocalSignupForm" in settings.py