# Django allauth customize signup

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a question about Django allauth-app. I have set up the allauth-app and have a standard login. Now I would like to store some additional information on signup. To be precise I would like to store the User's city, firstname and lastname. I tried to accomplish this task as explained in

[How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth:)

But even if I try to capture the first- and lastname where I shouldnt probably create a model, I fail due to this error:

```
    'module' object has no attribute 'CharField'
```

I have put new fields in the form and did this:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'yourproject.yourapp.forms.SignupForm'
```

Since I am using Django for a couple of days now it might be something very basic that I miss and I do try to read manuals but I am not close to solving this and I decided to ask you for help.
       Thanks in advance.

my forms.py look like this:

```
from django.forms import *   

class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Voornaam')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Achternaam')

def signup(self, request, user):
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.save()
```

my models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name='profiles')          
    first_name=models.CharField(_("First Name"), max_length=150)
    last_name=models.CharField(_("Last Name"), max_length=150)
```

The error appears in this line:

```
 first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Voornaam')
```

Aftermath -->
The import statement in my forms is wrong. It should rather look like this:

formy.py:

```
from django import forms
```

Comment: Please show your models/form

Comment: Your forms.py looks good except for the indentation. Was it a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Nah I think I destroyed the indentation with copy-pastying a couple of times.   At least PyCharm says that my indentation in the code im using is OK.

Comment: How are you importing the forms module in your forms.py?

Comment: @Vollmilchbb I did the same and its working fine for me. The only difference is with my import statement at top. I had `from django import forms`.

Comment: It was indeed a wrong import statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're importing the forms module is likely the issue. You either want to do:

`from django.forms import CharField`

where you explicitly import the fields you want to use

or preferably:

`from django import forms`

if you just want to import them all.

Comment: I swapped the line "from django.forms import *" with "from django.forms import forms" but unluckily I'm still getting the same Error namely: 'module' object has no attribute 'CharField'

Comment: But that's not what I wrote in my answer. You want to use `from django import forms`

Comment: Oh, Im sorry I didn't realize that. That indeed fixed my problem. By the way what is the difference here? django.forms and forms are two different things?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not 100% sure. I think it has to do with the way django's sub modules are structured. For most other things, saying `from app.module import *` should work.