# Add custom user using django-allauth extra data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-allauth

I would like to save data I get with allauth package after signing up using facebook.

I made a custom user :

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = adress_model.AddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

I would like to store all data in the database so I can easily access it from database.

P.S: If u can tell me how I can make a login page with button that will trigger it as well it would be great!

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `save()` method of the model to extract and save the data:

```
save(self, *wargs, **kwargs)
    social_account = self.socialaccount_set.get(provider="facebook")
    self.first_name = social_account.extra_data['first_name']
    super(User, self).save(*wargs, **kwargs)
```

Or you can use the provided signal by `allauth`:

```
allauth.socialaccount.signals.social_account_added(request, sociallogin)
```

Check here for signal docs: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html