# drango-allauth Cannot override both Signup and Signin form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization, django-allauth

I'm trying to custom the AllAuth interface.
I can override LoginForm and SignupForm separately, but if I override both of them, I got this error :

```
Module "app.forms" does not define a "BootstrapSignupForm" class
```

my forms :

```
class BootstrapLoginForm(LoginForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BootstrapLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['login'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control';
        self.fields['login'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'User name';

        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control';
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password';

class BootstrapSignupForm(SignupForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BootstrapSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control';
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'user name';
```

my settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'app.forms.BootstrapLoginForm'}
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'app.forms.BootstrapSignupForm'
```

But if I only keep one of them, it works.
Why is it not possible to override many of allauth forms at the same time ? Is there a workaround ? What is the googd practice to change AllAuth theme ? Is there a easy way to set up bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` represents a form that contains a few additional fields that are added to the signup form. So, it does not actually replace the real signup form, its fields only get merged into it.

If you really want to replace the actual forms, then you should indeed use `ACCOUNT_FORMS`. Simply add a signup key in there. Do note that there is also a `SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS` to take care of ...

See [How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth/12308807#12308807) for details on `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS`.

Comment: thank you! And I suggest django-widget-tweaks, it's a good way to edit forms fields classes.