# django-allauth: Custom signup doesn't save

Tags: django, django-forms, registration, django-allauth

I am trying to create a custom signup, filling fields of a `Profile` model that has a `OneToOne` relation to `User`. My form is displayed correctly but saving leads to nothing but a page refresh. Using the standard form coming with `django-allauth` works though.

In my `forms.py` I have a custom form that uses `def signup(self)` as the original creator has posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12308807/4758860). This function also seems to never get called.

**settings.py**

```
# allauth settings
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'accounts.forms.SignupForm'}
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'email',
               'placeholder': _('E-mail address')}))
    password1 = PasswordField(label=_("Password"))
    password2 = PasswordField(label=_("Password (again)"))

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'


    def signup(self, request, user):
        print "hi"
        print request.POST
        print user
        new_profile = Profile()
        new_profile.user = user
        new_profile['field1'] = self.cleaned_data['field1']
        new_profile['field2'] = self.cleaned_data['field2']
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call save() in the end

```
def signup(self, request, user):
        .....
        new_profile.save()
```