# customizing django allauth form

Tags: django-forms, django-allauth

I'm trying to add some additional fields to the allauth signup form (first_name and last_name). I'm thinking the best way to do this is to create a allauth SignupForm subclass and add my own fields (very new to django so please let me know if I'm going about this wrong)

I added

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'accounts.forms.UserCreateForm'
```

to my base settings file

and here is my accounts.forms.py...

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django import forms


class UserCreateForm(SignupForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "username", "password1", "password2")
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["first_name"].label = ''
        self.fields["first_name"].widget.attrs["placeholder"] = "First Name"
        self.fields["last_name"].label = ''
        self.fields["last_name"].widget.attrs["placeholder"] = "Last Name"
        self.fields["email"].label = ''
        self.fields["email"].widget.attrs["placeholder"] = "Email"
        self.fields["username"].label = ''
        self.fields["username"].widget.attrs["placeholder"] = "Username"
        self.fields["password1"].label = ''
        self.fields["password1"].widget.attrs["placeholder"] = "Password"
        self.fields["password2"].label = ''
        self.fields["password2"].widget.attrs["placeholder"] = "Confirm Password"
```

for some reason I keep getting the error ...

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing form class accounts.forms: "cannot import name 'SignupForm'"
```

Not sure why. Obviously there is a SignupForm in allauth.account.forms.py, seen here... 
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py

I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Any help you can give is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12308807/3415357

You do not need to inherit allauth.account.forms.SignupForm, you should inherit from forms.Form specify fields and write your custom signup function (username, email, password should stay intact)