# Remove email field from Django Allauth signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

How do I remove the email field from Django allauth signup? [No settings here show any option to remove it](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

Any idea?

EDIT: My custom form:

```
class AllauthSignupForm(forms.Form):

    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """ Required, or else it throws deprecation warnings """
        pass
```

**settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'draft1.forms.AllauthSignupForm'
```

Comment: ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED (=False) what about this ?

Comment: I've done `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False` but it still doesn't remove the email field from signup form (default is `False` anyway)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: inn your `settings.py`add

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
```

Then you might also want to add this if you want the user to log in with username

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
```

Alternatively:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS='yourcustomform'
```

And the form

```
class YourCustomForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', ...)
```

Comment: Still doesn't remove the email field from the signup form

Comment: Weird
I added alternative solution

Comment: Ah my mistake, I was using a custom form. However, when I remove `email` from my fields in the custom form it still doesn't remove the email field. I've added the code in my edit if you'd like to look.

Comment: [Isn't this thread similar to what you are describing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `exclude` the `email` field?

```
class AllauthSignupForm(forms.Form):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
        exclude = ('email',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('email')

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """ Required, or else it throws deprecation warnings """
        pass
```

Comment: Just tried that - it still doesn't work. Email field still in the form.

Comment: What if you do `self.fields.pop('email')` in `__init__`? Answer updated.

Comment: I'm using Python 3 so that `super` syntax does not work for me - could you update for python3?

Comment: That is Python 3 syntax.

Comment: Ah my mistake - I tried that and it still isn't working unfortunately. I added 'password2` to `exclude` and that also doesn't work - so it must be something different.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, so I went to External Libraries/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py and commented out lines 300-314 and 266-269. Try it out :)