# How am I supposed to add a field to a signup form in django-allauth? Docs vs Stackoverflow vs Blog posts

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-allauth

It appears that there are multiple ways to add a simple field to a `django-allauth` signup form.

From @danielfeldroy I see what's quoted below.

```
# SpyBookSignupForm inherits from django-allauth's SignupForm
class SpyBookSignupForm(SignupForm):

# Specify a choice field that matches the choice field on our user model
type = d_forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("SPY", "Spy"), ("DRIVER", "Driver")])

# Override the init method
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Call the init of the parent class
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Remove autofocus because it is in the wrong place
    del self.fields["username"].widget.attrs["autofocus"]

# Put in custom signup logic
def custom_signup(self, request, user):
    # Set the user's type from the form reponse
    user.type = self.cleaned_data["type"]
    # Save the user's type to their database record
    user.save()
```

But then, in the response to a ticket from https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/826 **pennersr** (django-allauth's founder)  states that all we have to do is:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Voornaam')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Achternaam')

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

And then add `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'yourproject.yourapp.forms.SignupForm'` to my settings.

See: [How to customize user profile when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth)

But then in the docs we have this: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#signup-allauth-account-forms-signupform

Where we do this:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

def save(self, request):

    # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
    # .save() returns a User object.
    user = super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).save(request)

    # Add your own processing here.

    # You must return the original result.
    return user
```

And we add `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'mysite.forms.MyCustomSignupForm'}ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'mysite.forms.MyCustomSignupForm'}` to the settings file.

So my basic question, **if we assume we just want to add a couple of fields, which is the right one**?

Because I have a really basic setup and none of the approaches work.

I get close with the one where we inherit the `forms.Form`. Well, I don't get any errors. But it doesn't actually save the input. Even though I can see the `cleaned()` input data through with `print()` statements.

I'm really confused and I hope that someone can help me sort out what is best approach.

Here's what I have.

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    opt_in = forms.BooleanField(label="Add me to the email list", help_text="Don't worry. We won't spam you.", initial=True, required=False)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.opt_in = self.cleaned_data['opt_in']
        user.save
```

And then in settings I have `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.CustomSignupForm'`

Comment: Are you using fields on the `User` model (or your custom User model) or trying to use fields on a user profile model?

Comment: I just tried the second method again (the one where SignupForm inherits from forms.Form). It still works perfectly, so instead of showing us the examples, you should probably show your actual code.

Comment: I added my code to clarify. The issue is that the Boolean is not saving. It is a custom user model and t does have the `opt_in` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if this is your code verbatim, the error is that you're not calling the save method, because the brackets are missing:

```py
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    opt_in = forms.BooleanField(label="Add me to the email list", help_text="Don't worry. We won't spam you.", initial=True, required=False)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.opt_in = self.cleaned_data['opt_in']
        user.save() # Note ()
```

And that should fix your problem

Comment: Boy am I embarrassed! That was it and I know better. Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't be. If you don't notice during typing, you won't see it, no matter how many times you look over it.