# Django Allauth: How to add more custom fields on signup form?

Tags: django, django-allauth

So, I'm trying to make a custom signup form while using Django allauth on my project. I've reached their [documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#signup-allauth-account-forms-signupform) and tried to apply it on my code.

In my forms.py I've put this:

```
class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
cpf_cnpj = forms.CharField(max_length=14)
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

def save(self, request):

    # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
    # .save() returns a User object.
    user = super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).save(request)

    # Add your own processing here.
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name= self.cleanedD_data['last_name']
    user.cpf_cnpj = self.cleaned_data['cpf_cnpj']
    user.save()
    # You must return the original result.
    return user
```

I've put the ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'mysite.forms.MyCustomSignupForm'} in settings.py as required too.

As you can see on the image linked below, it saves to the user their first and last name, but it doesnt save the cpf_cnpj field Value. What should I do to save this to the user?

[Admin Panel - Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEk4K.png)
[Signup Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgRkP.png)

Comment: Hey Jorge, when using stack overflow it’s best to show your attempts in the code you have written. When that isn’t included it seems as if you haven’t put forth your best effort which means less people will be willing to help.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303478/how-to-customize-user-profile-when-using-django-allauth

Comment: @DanielButler thank you for the advice. I've tried this tutorial linked, but when i logged in the admin page, It wouldn't show other fields i've added besides the first name and last name, on the user section of the admin page. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your forms.py add the fields like this to add an extra field in default user creation form provide by django

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class MyCustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    cpf_cnpj = forms.CharField(max_length=14)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'cpf_cnpj', ' first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

and acc to that change you views.py

```
from .forms import *

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyCustomSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:login')
    else:
        form = MyCustomSignupForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
 path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt seem to work. I edited my question as I tried to use the django-allauth documentation. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: cpf_cnpj = self.cleaned_data['cpf_cnpj'] try this and also remove extra d in last name

Comment: It still doesn't save cpf_cnpj in User. Should I make a Model to save this? If so, how?

Comment: u can use  django built in user creation form for creating sign up page

Comment: i changed the answer try that

Comment: everything is working, thank you very much. One last question, how could I get the data now? I've tried User.object.get(id=2), it returns the object, when using object.email i can get the value, but when I try object.cpf_cnpj, i get nothing.

Comment: that's a total different question

Comment: ask it as a new question